# issue in t:panelTabbedPan

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I have 2 tabs in my application and to implement them I have used tomahawk's "t:panelTabbedPane". code is as follows:

```
     <t:panelTabbedPane  align="center"  width="100%" serverSideTabSwitch="false" selectedIndex="#{bean.selectedIndex}"  rendered="#{bean.someValue}">


            <t:panelTab  style="text-align:left;" label="Initiate New Access">
```

But here the problem is with alignment of text in tabs. My requirement is to show the text left aligned in tabs and to implement this I have written this:

```
    style="text-align:left;"
```

But still these tabs showing the text center aligned. 
Please help me to solve this problem...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which text you want to show as left align? The code isn't complete.

You have to specify the style information to the component that is displaying the text.

Comment: <t:panelTab  style="text-align:left;" label="Initiate New Access">..the text specified in label , I want to show it left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify your labels' style in the `<t:panelTabbedPane>` component, not in the `<t:panelTab>`.

For the `<t:panelTabbedPane>` component you can specify these attributes:

- activeSubStyleClass
- activeTabStyleClass
- inactiveSubStyleClass
- inactiveTabStyleClass

I'm not sure which of these attributes will change the style desired.

Here you have the description of all the attributes related to `<t:panelTabbedPane>` component, I hope it will help: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_panelTabbedPane.html